# is it possible to pass id of the text box as a value of url in the url section of ajax function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, arcgis

Here I'm passing `arcgis` rest service as a value of text box, after submitting the value how to consume the service url json results on success?

```
  $("#submitp").click(function () {
       // alert('in');
        var data_spacial1 = $('#spacial1').val();
        alert(data_spacial1);
        getspacial1(data_spacial1);

    });

    function getspacial1(data_spacial1) {

        alert("in1");

        $.ajax({
            url: "data_spacial1",  // where data_spacial1=http://164.100.133.211:6080/arcgis/rest/services/SoilM/2016April18/MapServer/0?f=pjson
            data: { f: "json", where: "1=1", returnGeometry: false },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("got response: ", response);
                alert("in2");
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You literally just remove the quotes, so you're using the argument you passed in:

```
url: data_spacial1
```

E.g.:

```
function getspacial1(data_spacial1) {
    alert("in1");
    $.ajax({
        url: data_spacial1, // ***
        data: { f: "json", where: "1=1", returnGeometry: false },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("got response: ", response);
            alert("in2");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @shruthi: If `data_spacial1` contains the URL, the above will absolutely work. Update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
      <label >Spatial data url:</label>
      <input id="spacial1" placeholder="Enter Url" />
     <button  id="submitp" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>

Comment: $("#submitp").click(function () {
       // alert('in');
        var data_spacial1 = $('#spacial1').val();
        alert(data_spacial1);
        getspacial1(data_spacial1);

    });

Comment: function getspacial1(data_spacial1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: data_spacial1,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                $('#firstName').val(data.currentVersion);
                $('#layertype').val(data.type);
                
               
            }
        });

    }

Comment: if we give direct url in the url section than its working correctly